# Peculiar potential rounding issue in trigger

Tags: trigger

We have a formula field on a layout that performs a simple calculation.

List Price * size_factor * type_factor

the actual code is

```
IF( Unit_of_Measure__c = &quot;Subscription&quot; , ListPrice * size_factor__c * type_factor__c , ListPrice )
```

The precision is 18 and the scale 2

When we do this manually we get the following result

20,400 * 1.13 * 0.8 = **18,441.60**

What we see Salesforce calculate is  **18,360.00**

The only way we can arrive at that number is if we do the following

0.8 * 1.13 = 0.904 (rounded to two decimal places = 0.90)

giving the resultant calculation;

0.9 * 20,400 = 18,360

It appears that Salesforce performs the calculation right to left and rounds every step.

My question is would you expect to see this and is this mathematically correct?

I would expect a left to right execution with all the internal calculations being to 18 significant digits rounding the final result to 2 decimal places. Is this wrong?

**Update**

It turns out the 1.13 factor was actually 1.125 and just got displayed at 1.13.  `0.8 * 1.125 * 20,400 = 18,360`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, a colleague worked it out.

The factors are stored in the DB to 3 decimal places so 1.13 is actually in the DB as 1.125. If you use these numbers as per the DB then you get the results shown.

The problem is simply that the values entered and used have a higher precision than is displayed.

We will need to update the screens to match the data precision.

Thanks for all your help.

Murray

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?  How was Size_Factor__c defined (precision/scale), and why was it rounded to 2 digits when displayed?

Comment: In the object Size_Factor__c is defined as precision = 3 scale = 2. However when we look at the DB it is holding values to three decimal places e.g. 1.125. Why it was rounded to 2 decimal places is anynoes guess. It said it on the requirements or it didn't and the developer assumed it should be. This particular functionality was developed by a third party and we were just trying to figure out why the results appeared to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the ROUND() function and just indicate you would like to round to the nearest 2,3,4, or however many decimals you would like.  If you use the round function with 3 decimals, it should force the calculation to .904 instead of the .90 (rounding to 2 decimals) it is seeing now.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm

So you could change your formula to the following

```
IF( Unit_of_Measure__c = &quot;Subscription&quot; , ListPrice * ROUND(size_factor__c * type_factor__c, 3) , ListPrice )
```

Comment: We could do that but does this mean that the right to left order of execution is correct?

Comment: I am unsure about the order of execution, but the formula I updated above should give you the calculation you are looking for.

Comment: I'll take a look at using that option thanks. My concern is how many other calcs suffer from the same problem. I may have a lot of checking to do now.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that Salesforce is using fixed-point decimal to store values, and intermediate results of calculations will have that same precision.

I'm guessing that both `Size_Factor__c` and `Type_Factor__c` also have a precision of 2.

One possible solution would be to have a `Scale_Factor__c` formula field with a precision of 4 that holds the value of `Size_Factor__c * Type_Factor__c`, and then multiply `ListPrice` by that.  You'd want to verify that there isn't any loss of precision in calculating `Scale_Factor__c`.

The other solution is to use parenthesis to group the multiplication in a way to minimize loss of precision.  Multiply by the larger decimal first, especially when the second decimal is less than 1.0.

```
IF( Unit_of_Measure__c = "Subscription", (ListPrice * Size_Factor__c) * Type_Factor__c, ListPrice )
```

In this case, if you aren't going to overflow your variable you could scale your multiplication by 100 and then divide the final result by 100.

```
(ListPrice * (Size_Factor__c * (100 * Type_Factor__c))) / 100
```

Comment: I agree I could do that but the question is, is the apparent right to left execution mathematically correct, by design and well known (have I just missed it) or do I now have to check every single calculation throughout our Salesforce implementation. If all my developers/admins/business admins are assuming left to right and the rounding is being performed as you say then how many calculations in our complex sales system are incorrect.

Comment: Well, if you ignore rounding, left-to-right and right-to-left are the same.  `(A × B) × C` is mathematically equivalent to `A × (B × C)`